# Erro Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php

Sei que deve sim ter  outras respostas parecidas mas em nenhuma delas achei oque precisava. No banco possuo uma tabela com id, nome, version, upload e size. Preciso apenas pegar a versão do arquivo que selecionei pelo SELECT
o código esta a seguir:

```
<?php
$num = 1; 
if($num == 1){
    $sql = mysqli_query( $link,'SELECT * FROM files id = 2');
    $resource = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));

    while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
        echo " ID: ". $ln['id'];
        echo " Nome: " .$ln['nome'];
        echo " Versão: ". $ln['version'];
        echo " Upload: ". $ln['upload'];
        echo " Size: ". $ln['size'];
        echo "Deu certo";
        echo '<tr><td>'.$ln['version'].'</td>;
}
?>
```

Porém sempre que tento executar ele aparece o seguinte erro:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in.
Oque devo fazer?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array`; faltou um i

Comment: e `$result` não existe?

Comment: já verifiquei e acabei de corrigir, porém qual seria a forma certa de colocar o Select?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = 2`. Faltou o WHERE

Comment: mas ele não possui  " ", ou ' '

Answer (score 3):

Teu script tem no minimo 5 erros

Primeiro, esta linha esta errada:

```
$resource = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
```

Outra coisa estranha é que para a conexão você tem duas variáveis `$conexao` e `$link`, uma delas deve estar errada.

Aqui você setou `$resource`, mas creio que o queria era `$result`

Fora que você esta passado o resultado de um `mysqli_query` em outro:

```
$sql = mysqli_query( $link,'SELECT * FROM files id = 2');
$resource = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
```

Outro erro é que falta o `WHERE` no teu SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM files id = 2
```

Deveria ser:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = 2
```

O que **não faz sentido algum**

E você esta misturando a API antiga do `mysql` com a API nova chamada `mysqli`, o correto seria:

favorita
Sei que deve sim ter outras respostas parecidas mas em nenhuma delas achei oque precisava. No banco possuo uma tabela com id, nome, version, upload e size. Preciso apenas pegar a versão do arquivo que selecionei pelo SELECT o código esta a seguir:

```
<?php
$num = 1; 
if($num == 1){

    $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = 2') or die(mysqli_error($link));

    while ($ln = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        ...
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
```

### Um exemplo bem simples de mysqli

```
<?php
//$link é a variavel da "conexão"
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* Verifica erros */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT ...') or die(mysqli_error($link));

/* array numerica */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
}

/* array associativa */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Nome"], $row["Sobrenome"]);
}

/* associativa e numerica */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["Sobrenome"]);
}

/* libera a memoria */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* fecha a conexão */
mysqli_close($link);
```

### Leia a documentação

uma dica, não saia fazendo as coisas aleatóriamente, documentações existem para serem usadas, segue os links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html